# SslStream AuthenticateAsClient fails in Ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net-core, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to connect to server which requires client authentication with a certificate.

I run this code:

```
var tcpClient = new TcpClient("host", 443);
var sslStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream(), false,
                            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
                            new LocalCertificateSelectionCallback(SelectLocalCertificate));

X509Certificate certificate = new X509Certificate("pkcs12 file", "password");
X509CertificateCollection certificates = new X509CertificateCollection();
certificates.Add(certificate);

sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("host", certificates, SslProtocols.Default, false);
```

SelectLocalCertificate returns the appropriated certificate and
ValidateServerCertificate always return true.

I'm running this code using .net core 2.1 and when I run this in Windows 10, everything works well.
When I run the same code in Ubuntu 18.04, I have an exception with an error message

"Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream"

I have tried several things. I have changed the value of SslProtocols parameter.
I have tried to run my code changing ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol
without success.
On Windows 10 my code works fine but in Ubuntu 18.04 I have the previous error.

Comment: See whether this fits: [Adding certificate chain to TLS 1.2 connection in .NET core 2.1](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32427). MacOSX related.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks. Really useful your answer.

Comment: @Jimi but problem persists. It's really interesting your answer but not solve my problem. Thanks.